# Third-party apps not intalam

Tags: apps

Hi I am not able to install third party apps, it downloads normally just does not install help me[image]

Answer (score 0):

First open Terminal and visit your Downloads folder by typing:
`cd Downloads`

Next you need to depackage(extract) the installed deb files using `dpkg` as below:

`sudo dpkg -i <your-.deb-package-name.deb>`

Example: For your installation type `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

Repeat for all .deb files.

ALTERNATIVELY:

Right click the .deb file and select Open with > Software Center

Comment: no terminal asks to put the password so I try to type more will not, does not appear and the second alternative does not open in the center of apps, I do not know why

Comment: @GuilhermeCursi You just type the password. You won't see any dots like windows. Just type your password and press "Enter"